# Strategy pattern not working: What am I doing wrong?

Tags: php, design-patterns

I am a very beginning in PHP and Design Patterns. I have been studying the amazing Head First Design patterns. So, I have been trying to translate the original to PHP. However, I must be doing things very wrong, because it is not working. Can you help me?

```
<?php

interface FlyBehavior{
    public function fly();
}

class FlyWithWings implements FlyBehavior{
    public function fly(){
        echo "I am flying!";
    }
}

class FlyNoWay implements FlyBehavior{
    public function fly(){
        echo "I cannot fly!";
    }
}

interface QuackBehavior{
    public function quack();
}


class Quack implements QuackBehavior{
    public function quack(){
        echo "Quack";
    }
}

class MuteQuack implements QuackBehavior{
    public function quack(){
        echo "Silence";
    }
}

class Squeak implements QuackBehavior{
    public function quack(){
        echo "Squeak";
    }
}

abstract class Duck{
    protected $quackBehavior;
    protected $flyBehavior;

    public function performQuack(){
        $this->$quackBehavior->quack();
    }    

    public function performFly(){
        $this->$flyBehavior->fly();
    }

    abstract public function display();    

    public function swim(){
        echo "All ducks float, even decoy";
    }

}

class MallardDuck extends Duck{
    public function __construct(){
        $this->quackBehavior=new Quack();
        $this->flyBehavior=new FlyWithWings();
    }
    public function display(){
        echo "I am real Mallard duck!";
    }
}

$mallard=new MallardDuck();
$mallard->performQuack();
$mallard->performFly();


?>
```

When I run I get the error "Undefined variable: quackBehavior" in line "$this->$quackBehavior->quack();" inside "abstract class Duck".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error says it all

```
public function performQuack(){
        $this->$quackBehavior->quack();
    }    

    public function performFly(){
        $this->$flyBehavior->fly();
    }
```

should be

```
public function performQuack(){
        $this->quackBehavior->quack();
    }    

    public function performFly(){
        $this->flyBehavior->fly();
    }
```

`$this->quackBehaviory` refers to a property of your class.

`$quackBehaviory` means that it's a function scoped variable.

So to access the class property you need to use `$this->quackBehaviory`

Comment: Is there an explanation for this? Why dont I need this?

Comment: Thank you! It solved the execution problem but now two "Quacks" related to the class Quack arises. Do you know the reason?

Comment: @DanielTheRocketMan The explanation is [variable variables](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php)

Comment: @DanielTheRocketMan I have added some note on the last question u asked.

Answer (score 2):

Remove the `$` from `$this->$quackBehavior->quack();` and `$this->$flyBehavior->fly();` i.e. infront of `$quackBehavior` and `$flyBehavior`

Should be like this....

```
 $this->quackBehavior->quack(); //<--- Under your performQuack()
```

and

```
 $this->flyBehavior->fly(); //<--- Under your performFly()
```

Comment: It solved the execution problem but now two "Quacks" related to the class Quack arises. Do you know the reason?